# Is there no way to use redirecttoaction() function after download excel response.end() in mvc?

Tags: model-view-controller

Is there no way to use redirect to action() function  after download excel response.end()in mvc???
i am getting this issue from long and looking for a proper and good answer??
if answer is no .so please suggest any other technique for this.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

tnq for ur support.
Refer bellow link:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/312629/prb-threadabortexception-occurs-if-you-use-response-end-response-redir

i already try this .but if we use response.redirect  after response.end() its giving **Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent.** error.
and if we add before response.end() its getting redirect only but no such excel file is downloading after that.

and second solution for this:
please tell we can add two headers while downloading file?? i am already using  **Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=QuarterlyReport.csv")**.

please look into that.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Refer bellow link:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/312629/prb-threadabortexception-occurs-if-you-use-response-end-response-redir

OR

Response.AddHeder("Refresh","4;url= your redirect URL");

4=4 time delay before refresh.

Comment: any response into below query??